# How do I use tortoisegitmerge with mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisegit, tortoisegitmerge

I'm using mercurial for revision control in Windows, but I'd like to use a nice merge tool like TortoiseGitMerge.  How can I tell Mercurial to use TortoiseGitMerge for merge conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have installed TortoiseGit.

Then, edit or create `%userprofile%\.hgrc` (e.g. `c:\users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.hgrc`) and add the following:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.tortoisegitmerge = c:/Program Files/TortoiseGIT/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe

[merge-tools]
tortoisegitmerge.args = -base $base -mine $local -theirs $other -merged $output
```

Comment: Terrible bad. 1. `[extdiff]` section means you have to have extdiff extension enabled (but you say nothing about it) 2. **Full** merge-tool description is more than one line 3. For new merge-tool **now** extdiff isn't needed at all 4. `tortoisegitmerge.args` contain errors in writing

Comment: I just entered what worked for me.  Sorry you didn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

*Good* [merge-tools] section for TortoiseGitMerge (extracted from TortoiseHG's `hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc`) for **single merge-tool** only ([Merge Tool Configuration](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) wiki-page used for reference)

```
tortoisegitmerge.args=/base:$base /mine:$local /theirs:$other /merged:$output
tortoisegitmerge.regkey=Software\TortoiseGit
tortoisegitmerge.regkeyalt=Software\Wow6432Node\TortoiseGit
tortoisegitmerge.regname=TMergePath
tortoisegitmerge.checkchanged=True
tortoisegitmerge.gui=True
```

For more than 1 merge tool `tortoisegitmerge.priority` key with some priority have to added. In order to ignore priority-list and use always preselected from possible choices merge-tool, use

```
[ui]
merge = tortoisegitmerge
```

In global or repository-specific ini-file